# Get total since a certain date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea how I can get the total amount since a certain year (2001) in a column

I have this table

```
ID | date
==========
1  | 2001
2  | 2001
3  | 2002
4  | 2003
5  | 2003
7  | 2003
8  | 2004
9  | 2004
10 | 2006
```

I like to get:

```
date | count | total
====================
2001 | 2     | 2
2002 | 1     | 3
2003 | 3     | 6
2004 | 2     | 8
2005 | 0     | 8
2006 | 1     | 9
```

Basically it say year 2001 has 2 in the current year and 2 in total, 2002 has 1 in the current year and 3 in total (from the year 2001), 2003 has 3 in the current year and 6 in total /from year 2001 and 2002), and so on

Comment: Are you looking to do this purely with SQL?

Comment: Where did the column "total"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum in the `total` column.  Here is a way to do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select date, count(*) as `count`,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.date <= t.date) as total
from table t
where date > 2000
group by date;
```

EDIT:

If you want all dates, then you need to generate them and join them in:

```
select dates.date, count(*) as `count`,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.date <= dates.date) as total
from (select 2001 as date union all
      select 2002 union all
      select 2003 union all
      select 2004 union all
      select 2005 union all
      select 2006
     ) dates left outer join
     table t
     on dates.date = t.date
where t.date > 2000
group by dates.date;
```

Comment: He wants all the dates,even those that dont exist.

Comment: @Mihai . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I missed that subtlety.

Comment: ok, I like this approach but as mentioned I don't have years. I have timestamps. So can I use a something like `timestamp/yearinseconds+1970` which gives me the (unrounded) year?

Comment: @revaxarts . . . Changing the question after people have attempted to answer it is impolite.  You should ask another question with appropriate data for your problem.  You can reference this one, highlighting the differences in how the new question really is different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, my mistake. I just like to have a clear questions. I'll open another